# Bootstrap resizes my original image - I want it to stay how it originally is

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make two columns with bootstrap - text on the right, and a photo on the left. I want the photo to fill up the entire white screen of the left side, but at 100% width that is how much the image automatically fills. How do I change this?

I am relatively new to HTML+CSS, and this is an assignment so any tips would be helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img\favicon.ico">
  <title>Headspace</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="barAtTop"></div>

  <div class="site_title">
    <h1>HEADSPACE</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="motto" style="font-size:1vw;">
    <i>"To empower young people to have the confidence and skills to gain meaningful employment."</i>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" onclick="openDropDown()">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="team.html">Meet the Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="join.html">Join Now</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="main-page-image">
        <img src="img\teenager.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="about-headspace">
        <h1>ABOUT HEADSPACE</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis vel tortor eu ultrices. Suspendisse id luctus lorem. Donec sed fringilla odio. Morbi tristique luctus euismod. Morbi et lectus sed tortor pulvinar pulvinar cursus id turpis. Vestibulum
          eu elit erat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image can't outgrow the parent element it is inside of. So, when you put your image inside of a "col-sm-6", that limits its size to the size of its parent container. The solution would be to put the image inside of a larger parent element.

Comment: how would I put it in a larger parent element but still make it resizable with bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I understood the question correct the image is not filling in the `col-sm-6` element?</s>

Try changing `max-width` to `width`. Example:

`<img src="img\teenager.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">`

Use a custom row class and style it flexed and stretched to get the column to fill. Then we can simply add object-fit for the image itself.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main-page-image {
  overflow:hidden;
}

#main-page-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row card-container">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="main-page-image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6" id="about-headspace">
      <h1>ABOUT HEADSPACE</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis vel tortor eu ultrices. Suspendisse id luctus lorem. Donec sed fringilla odio. Morbi tristique luctus euismod. Morbi et lectus sed tortor pulvinar pulvinar cursus id turpis. Vestibulum
        eu elit erat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edits made. I think this is what you're looking for. There is still some padding on the column and the main parent container that could cause some undesired whitespace. Simply set those to `padding: 0;` if you'd like.